# How to delete multiple listbox items and update that in the rowsource?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a column that is updated dynamically using a text box. I am able to update the column using the text box and those values are updated in the list box.

I tried to delete multiple data from list box. But it is showing me error.
I need to get the data removed from list box as well as the worksheet column without and updating the column by removing the spaces and moving up.

My data column that is used to feed data to list box is dynamic. Ending range is not fixed.

I am getting a variable not defined error, if I make some tweaks I will get debug error or errors with codes

My code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
 Dim iItem As Long, iRow As Long

    With Sheet3 'reference Sheet3
        Set r1 = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) ' set current data range
    End With

    With Me.ListBox1 'reference your list box
        iItem = .ListCount - 1 ' start from last listbox item
        Do
            If .Selected(iItem) Then ' if current listbox item selected
                For iRow = r1.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1 'loop through data range rows from bottom to top
                    If r1.Cells(iRow).Value = .List(iItem) Then r1.Cells(iRow).EntireRow.Delete 'if current selected listbox index matches current data range cell value then delete this latter entire row
                Next
                .RemoveItem (iItem) ' remove selected item from the listbox
            End If
            iItem = iItem - 1 'update listbox item to the "next" one (i.e. the one above)
        Loop While iItem >= 0 ' loop till reaching first listbox item
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub ListBox1_Click()

End Sub

Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Range("A2").Select
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Please Add the component name")

Else

    ActiveCell = TextBox1.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

    ListBox1.RowSource = "Sheet3!A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Call resetForm


End If
End Sub

Sub resetForm()
TextBox1.Value = ""
TextBox1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: You're getting a not defined error because you didn't declare `C1`.

Comment: how it has to be declared?

Comment: It would be declared the same as `r1`, so in your case: `C1 As Range`. When using a `For Each...Next` statement, the two variables should be the same data type.

Comment: i declared.. now it is not showing error. But no selected item is removed from the list box

Comment: Your code appears to want to delete the row, not the listbox item. `C1.EntireRow.Delete` has nothing to do with the listbox. And why are you wanting to "Bold" `C1` when you are going to immediately delete it?

Comment: But you need to look into the `ListBox1.RemoveItem()` method.

Comment: actually i need to select some values from list box..then if i click remove button it should remove from list box as well as the source column and it should move the column cells up...rowsource is ListBox1.RowSource = "Sheet3!A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Answer (score 1):

when deleting items from `Collections` (like rows in a `Range` o items in a `ListBox` are) you should proceed from bottom to top and avoid both skipping items and processing nonexistent ones

like follows (explanations in comments)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim r1 As Range
    Dim iItem As Long, iRow As Long

    With Sheet3 'reference Sheet3
        Set r1 = .Range("A2:A" & .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row) ' set current data range
    End With

    With Me.ListBox1 'reference your list box
        iItem = .ListCount - 1 ' start from last listbox item
        Do
            If .Selected(iItem) Then ' if current listbox item selected
                For iRow = r1.Rows.Count To 1 Step -1 'loop through data range rows from bottom to top
                    If r1.Cells(iRow).Value = .List(iItem) Then r1.Cells(iRow).EntireRow.Delete 'if current selected listbox index matches current data range cell value then delete this latter entire row
                Next
                .RemoveItem (iItem) ' remove selected item from the listbox
            End If
            iItem = iItem - 1 'update listbox item to the "next" one (i.e. the one above)
        Loop While iItem >= 0 ' loop till reaching first listbox item
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: which line is throwing it?

Comment: debug took me to this line  .RemoveItem (iItem) ' remove selected item from the listbox

Comment: how to delete only that specific cell and not the entire row? i have only single column data

Comment: I tested it with no issue, so may be it's related to some strange data values from other pieces of code. use Immediate Window (CTRL-G to pop it put while in the VBA IDE) and check your relevant variables (e.g.: type `?iItem` or `?Me.ListBox1.Count` and then press return) to see what's going on at that point

Comment: _"how to delete only that specific cell and not the entire row?"_  this seems not to be related with the error you say is thrown from `.RemoveItem (iItem)` code line. Do the variables checks as per my last comment and see what's happening

Comment: @qwww, any feedback?

Comment: i ran it again..got same error..then i could see that the value of iItem was once 5, then it became 6 in next run,, then finally 2 in last run

Comment: `iItem ` is being decremented by `iItem = iItem - 1 ` line:  how can you have it pass from 5 to 6? you'd better show the whole code

Comment: it is getting removed... when i check the worksheet, i can see that removal is happening..but it is showing error...is it because the update listbox is not shown?

Comment: when the error hist the line `.RemoveItem (iItem)`, click "debug" button and then typ the following in Immediate Window : `?Me.ListBox1.Count` and press return to see both if there's still some valid reference to the userform and its ListBox component and how many values there are left

Comment: Sorry, my mistake: you have to type : ?Me.ListBox1.ListCount

Comment: how can i remove those items and show the updated listbox?

Comment: to delete all elements from a list box named after `ListBox1` you simply use `Me.ListBox1.Clear`. If my answer solved your original question, please consider marking it as accepted. thank you

Comment: no its not delete all elements..delete the selected elements, then show what is remaining

Comment: then use the code in my answer. in my test it worked so if you have issues it may be a matter of your actual scenario (data and its _structure_). you may then want to step thorugh the code: while in VBA IDE press F8 and step through each code line one by one, and query relevant variable state/value through Immediate Window (CTRL-G to pop it out)

Comment: i did this and it took me to Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Range("A2").Select
End Sub this part and after end sub, it loaded the userform

Comment: so.. go on: fill userform with some sample data and click the wanted button. and then keep on stepping through your code and see what's happening

Comment: now it showed error and took me to this line :  erow = "Sheet3!A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Comment: actually  "Sheet3!A2:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row  this is the column from which my labels are to be created and the count of this column is the number of texboxes that has to be created. values have to be stored adjacebt to each